# Using sed command in for loop across multiple servers

Tags: ssh, sed, for

I am trying to manipulate the same text file across multiple hosts. The command I currently have it:

```
for host in $(cat /etc/hosts | grep text | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sort -u); do
    ssh $host \
    sudo sed -i "s/enabled = 1/enabled = 0/" /etc/yum.repos.d/testing.repo
done
```

The sed command itself works locally on the host with no problems however when I run it here, I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the issue, but you have a [uuoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)  ;-)

Comment: @RoVo Old habbits :)

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
for host in $(grep test /etc/hosts | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sort -u); do
    ssh $host 'sudo sed -i "s/enabled = 1/enabled = 0/" /etc/yum.repos.d/testing.repo'
done
```

we should wrap around the remote commands with quotes.

Comment: Pointing out the solution: The extra quotes around the remote commands.  Also, would be better with a `read` loop (`ssh -n` would be needed).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change like this

```
for host in $(cat /etc/hosts | grep text | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sort -u); do
   ssh $host \
   "sudo sed -i \"s/enabled = 1/enabled = 0/\" /etc/yum.repos.d/testing.repo"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the command that is to be executed on the remote host relies on the quoting to be properly handled. The quotes needs to be evaluated as part of the command on the remote side, not on the local host.  This means that the command needs an extra level of quotes.

Since your current attempt does not properly quote the command, it is split on whitespaces on the remote host.  The `sed` command then becomes the equivalent of locally running

```
sed -i s/enabled = 1/enabled = 0/ /etc/yum.repos.d/testing.repo
```

which, as the error message says, contains an `s` command that is not properly terminated.

Also, looping over a command substitution is inelegant and hazardous.  The value that the substitution expands to would be  split into words on whitespaces, and the words would then undergo filename generation (globbing).  It also requires the command substitution to be fully expanded before the loop could even start its first iteration.

Instead, use a `read` loop:

```
awk '/text/ && !seen[$1]++ { print $1 }' |
while IFS= read -r remote; do
    ssh -n "$remote" \
        'sudo sed -i "s/enabled = 1/enabled = 0/" /etc/yum.repos.d/testing.repo'
done
```

Note the `ssh -n` here. It stops `ssh` from reading its standard input stream, which would otherwise have it read the hosts that the `awk` command outputs.  Also, any variable expansion should be double quoted (unless you know in what contexts this is not needed).

Another way to solve this issue would obviously be to, instead of editing the existing file on the various remote hosts, push a *new* copy of the file to each machine (possibly using `scp` or `rsync`).  This would however require that the file should look the same on each host.